# NodeJS: What is default server's port?

Tags: node.js

We often see example hello world code for Node that creates an Http Server, starts listening on a port:

```
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    console.log("Hello World!!!");
});
server.listen();   //This will start our node server
```

So, in above what is the default server's port in which it is started?

Answer (score 2):

If you check the `expressjs` official documentation of `app.listen([port[, host[, backlog]]][, callback])` method [here](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.listen)

> You see that there comes: *If port is omitted or is 0, the operating
> system will assign an arbitrary unused port, which is useful for cases
> like automated tasks (tests, etc.).*

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_listen_port_host_backlog_callback):

> If port is omitted or is 0, the operating system will assign an arbitrary unused port, which can be retrieved by using server.address().port after the 'listening' event has been emitted.